# How can we sort view result, depend on cookie set or not

Tags: 7, views

I have created a view to display slideshow from specific content type.

Now I have a condition that if visitor is new then slideshow will sort according to custom field "*slider order*".
And if user visited already then slideshow will sort according to post date.

I have tried this from "`hook_views_query_alter`" but I want this to be done from view only.

I applied some custom sorting in views but not working (actually I have no idea about custom sorting in views)

Please let me know the conditions.

*Fields:* `title, description, Image`

*Filter:* `content type= slider`

*Sorting:* `Post date (desc)`   [here I need your help]

Answer (score 0):

- For any field you want to pull a value from a Cookie you add an exposed filter, here I add a contextual filter for the field, here a node->title:

  [image]
- Then we configure the filter to pull a value from the URL. If none is provided we define how to find the value via PHP code. This is the secret to pulling the value from a $_COOKIE value.

[image]

- Then we supply a blurb of code to read the Cookie value:

[image]